# changing grid options size for col-lg to > 1400 on a specific page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to `bootstrap 3` and I am currently using the grid systems.

I have a page in which I wanted to change such that `.col-lg-` is applied to screen width of `> 1400px`. I only want to change only for this class, is this possible?

If yes then how do I do this? I wanted to keep the settings for `.col-lg-` as 1200px (the default) for all other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can write @media queries such as:

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .col-lg- {
     //your code goes here
  }
}
```